# Matter.js Apply Force Onto Body Using Angle and Power Level

Tags: javascript, matter.js

I am currently trying to apply force to a body using a degree (a float between -90 and 90), and a forceLevel (a float between 0 and 1). `Body.applyForce()` only allows me to provide x and y power levels.

What I am trying to achieve:

I want to be able to drag back from a position, and have my body launch towards the other directions with the power of the launch based on how much the user dragged back.

Here is my code for getting the angle and the power level.

```
var cachedPosition = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0
};
document.addEventListener("mousedown", (e) => {
    cachedPosition.x = e.clientX
    cachedPosition.y = e.clientY
})

document.addEventListener("mouseup", (e) => {
    var degree = "INVALID";
    var difX = cachedPosition.x - e.clientX
    var difY = cachedPosition.y - e.clientY
    if (difX > 0 && difY < 0) {
        var degree = getDegree(difX, difY)
    } if (difX < 0 && difY < 0) {
        var degree = -getDegree(Math.abs(difX), difY); // Negative degree if drag is towards bottom right.
    }

    var power = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(difX, 2)+Math.pow(difY, 2))/1000
})
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Without giving details of the problem you are facing, it is difficult to help you.

Comment: Hello! Thank you for the advice, but I am confused on how I could improve my problem. I believe I've provided sufficient information. Is it possible for you to provide me with a specific example of how I could improve my question?

Comment: Show how you are trying to use `applyForce`. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I don't see `applyForce` or any MJS code here at all. MJS docs have exact code for "I want to be able to drag back from a position, and have my body launch towards the other directions with the power of the launch based on how much the user dragged back.", so have you checked that out? https://brm.io/matter-js/demo/#slingshot. It's a pretty well-known usage of MJS and there are other tutorials on youtube, for example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3iuVfIsB8Y4, https://github.com/BWitz/MatterJS-Slingshot-Game, https://slides.com/scallemang/matter-js

Comment: Furthermore, I'd usually use a mouse constraint rather than traditional DOM listeners like this.

Comment: I had no idea slingshot existed! I will make sure to try that out.